# Multiple Google charts - displaying a tooltip /crosshair on all charts at once

Tags: charts, google-visualization

I'm trying to draw two separate Google charts and have them share a common x axis. The idea is that I can hover over one chart and see the tooltip appear on the other chart at the correct date.

A little like this but with a tooltip. The focusTarget attribute works great on a single chart, just not both.

[image]

I figure I have to somehow create a common date column but am not sure how to go about it.

My working (abbr.) code (so far) to display the charts.

```
var link = function(scope,element,attrs) {

  google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawUsageChart);

  google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChartOne);

  function drawChartOne() {

    var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
    data.addColumn('date', 'Date');
    data.addColumn('number', 'Sessions');

    var sessions = [786, 450, 866, 814, 192, 466, 984, 780, 922, 458, 786, 758, 701, 831, 901, 557, 114, 393, 689, 658, 103, 837, 164, 727, 593, 193, 945, 583, 948, 338];

    var start = new Date(1458345600 * 1000);
    var date;

    var dates = [];

    for(var i = 0; i < sessions.length; i++) {
      var newDate = start.setDate(start.getDate() + 1);
      data.addRow([new Date(newDate), sessions[i]]);
    }

    var options = {title:'Wot',
      height:300,
      lineWidth: 1.5,
      legend: { position: 'none' },
      crosshair: {
        trigger: 'both',
        orientation: 'vertical'
      },
      focusTarget: 'category',
    };

    var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('mcs-chart'));
    chart.draw(data, options);
  }

  function drawChartTwo() {

    var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
    data.addColumn('date', 'Date');
    data.addColumn('number', 'Other Sessions');

    var sessions = [786, 450, 866, 814, 192, 466, 984, 780, 922, 458, 786, 758, 701, 831, 901, 557, 114, 393, 689, 658, 103, 837, 164, 727, 593, 193, 945, 583, 948, 338];

    var start = new Date(1458345600 * 1000);
    var date;

    var dates = [];

    for(var i = 0; i < sessions.length; i++) {
      var newDate = start.setDate(start.getDate() + 1);
      // dates.push(new Date(newDate));
      data.addRow([new Date(newDate), sessions[i]]);
    }

    var options = {
      title:'WOOOOT',
      height:300,
      lineWidth: 1.5,
      legend: { position: 'none' },
      crosshair: {
        trigger: 'both',
        orientation: 'vertical'
      },
      focusTarget: 'category',
    };

    var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('snr-chart'));
    chart.draw(data, options);
  }

};
```

Comment: maybe try [firing the same event](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/dev/events#firing-an-event) on the other chart as the one that is captured

Comment: Isn't that going to add major overhead to things. Loads of data points to navigate through.

Comment: wouldn't think so, the captured event provides the data point

Comment: I'll give it a shot later and report back Captain

Answer (score 3):

tried using `google.visualization.events.trigger` to sync the two `'onmouseover'` events

although the `'onmouseover'` event fires on the other chart, the tooltip isn't shown

apparently, [it's not possible to force a tooltip to display](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15736340/5090771)

you would have to write your own using the coordinates of the data point

but you could sync the charts on `'select'`

expanding on the example in the question...

```js
google.charts.load('current', {
  callback: function () {

    var chart1;
    var chart2;

    var data1 = new google.visualization.DataTable();
    var data2 = new google.visualization.DataTable();

    var outDiv1 = document.getElementById('mcs-chart-event');
    var outDiv2 = document.getElementById('snr-chart-event');

    var options1 = {title:'Wot',
      height:300,
      lineWidth: 1.5,
      legend: { position: 'none' },
      crosshair: {
        trigger: 'both',
        orientation: 'vertical'
      },
      focusTarget: 'category',
    };

    var options2 = {
      title:'WOOOOT',
      height:300,
      lineWidth: 1.5,
      legend: { position: 'none' },
      crosshair: {
        trigger: 'both',
        orientation: 'vertical'
      },
      focusTarget: 'category',
    };


    drawChartOne(data1);
    drawChartTwo(data2);

    google.visualization.events.addListener(chart1, 'select', function () {
      chart2.setSelection(chart1.getSelection());
    });

    google.visualization.events.addListener(chart2, 'select', function () {
      chart1.setSelection(chart2.getSelection());
    });

    google.visualization.events.addListener(chart1, 'onmouseover', function (properties) {
      outDiv1.innerHTML = 'chart1.onmouseover' + JSON.stringify(properties);
      google.visualization.events.trigger(chart2, 'onmouseover', properties);
    });

    google.visualization.events.addListener(chart2, 'onmouseover', function (properties) {
      outDiv2.innerHTML = 'chart2.onmouseover' + JSON.stringify(properties);
    });

    chart1.draw(data1, options1);
    chart2.draw(data2, options2);

    function drawChartOne(data) {
      data.addColumn('date', 'Date');
      data.addColumn('number', 'Sessions');

      var sessions = [786, 450, 866, 814, 192, 466, 984, 780, 922, 458, 786, 758, 701, 831, 901, 557, 114, 393, 689, 658, 103, 837, 164, 727, 593, 193, 945, 583, 948, 338];

      var start = new Date(1458345600 * 1000);
      var date;

      var dates = [];

      for(var i = 0; i < sessions.length; i++) {
        var newDate = start.setDate(start.getDate() + 1);
        data.addRow([new Date(newDate), sessions[i]]);
      }

      chart1 = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('mcs-chart'));
    }

    function drawChartTwo(data) {
      data.addColumn('date', 'Date');
      data.addColumn('number', 'Other Sessions');

      var sessions = [786, 450, 866, 814, 192, 466, 984, 780, 922, 458, 786, 758, 701, 831, 901, 557, 114, 393, 689, 658, 103, 837, 164, 727, 593, 193, 945, 583, 948, 338];

      var start = new Date(1458345600 * 1000);
      var date;

      for(var i = 0; i < sessions.length; i++) {
        var newDate = start.setDate(start.getDate() + 1);
        data.addRow([new Date(newDate), sessions[i]]);
      }

      chart2 = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('snr-chart'));
    }
  },
  packages: ['corechart']
});
```

```html
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div id="mcs-chart"></div>
<div id="snr-chart"></div>
<div id="mcs-chart-event"></div>
<div id="snr-chart-event"></div>
```

Comment: Let me wire something up and test myself. I've actually got 4-6+ charts per page so keeping them in sync is going to be a nightmare. Was trying to think of another way to do - i.e. using a common x axis. Since I think they all need to be in-sync for the cross hairs etc. to appear correctly.

Comment: Yes, very helpful. I had zero place to start. Let me see how I get on before accepting etc :)